# git reset --hard doesn't work after adjusting the Head

Tags: git, git-reset

When I do `git reset --hard` to discard changes in current working copy, nothing get discarded.

Here is what I did prior to this problem:
I moved the Head back 3 commits 
`git reset HEAD~3`
Then I wanted to go back to the latest commit, and I thought this would do it
`git checkout -`
What actually this done is checking out the development branch with changes that I don't want.
Now I want to go back to my previous branch without commiting these changes but I cannot switch branch because of these changes.
`git reset --hard` does nothing.
A also tried to stash the changes, they get stashed, but the working copy won't remove the changes in my working copy.

Edit:
Here is the output of git status:

```
On branch development
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/development'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Slide Down /SlideDownViewController.swift
    deleted:    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Slide Down /SlideDownViewController.xib
    deleted:    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Tabs/Swiping Controller /PageCollectionViewCell.swift
    deleted:    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Tabs/Swiping Controller /SwipingViewController.swift
    deleted:    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Tabs/Swiping Controller /SwipingViewController.xib

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Slide Down (Whitespace Conflict)/
    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Slide Down/
    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Tabs/Swiping Controller (Whitespace Conflict)/
    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Tabs/Swiping Controller/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Could you paste the result of `git status`?

Comment: "I cannot do `git reset --hard`" is different from "`git reset --hard` does nothing", the first means that there is a reason why you can't use that command, the second is that you tried using that command and it didn't do what you expected it to do. Can you explain which one it is? Also, `git reset --hard` usually needs to be told what you want it to reset *to*. Did you do that?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes `git reset --hard` does nothing. I want to reset all changes so no need to specify a particular file.

Comment: The fact that you put this under Dropbox is missing from the question!

Comment: @torek You're right. I didn't expect it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I understand that you want all changes to go away. `git status` reveals that you have some deleted files and also some untracked.
You can undelete those:

```
    deleted:    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Slide Down /SlideDownViewController.swift
    deleted:    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Slide Down /SlideDownViewController.xib
    deleted:    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Tabs/Swiping Controller /PageCollectionViewCell.swift
    deleted:    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Tabs/Swiping Controller /SwipingViewController.swift
    deleted:    Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Tabs/Swiping Controller /SwipingViewController.xib
```

by executing e.g. `git checkout -- .`

Those untracked are not handled by git, as they were not added to it. You can delete them by hand if that is what you want `rm -r Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Slide\ Down\ (Whitespace\ Conflict)` (and so on) and they will disappear from `git status`.

Comment: I managed to delete the files. But still cannot undelete the deleted files. The command `git checkout -- .` when run, brings back the untracked files. It's like that the deleted files are untracked!.

Comment: Now I realized that there are whitespaces at the ends of folder names... I have never encountered such problem (I follow the rule to avoid whitespaces in paths) so the below solution is just my guess: ```rm -r Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Slide\ Down\ \(Whitespace\ Conflict\)/
rm -r Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Tabs/Swiping\ Controller\ \(Whitespace\ Conflict\)/

git add Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Slide\ Down/
git add Muqeem/Modules/Muqeem/Tabs/Swiping\ Controller/

git commit -a -m "Fixed problems with spaces at the ends of folders"``` Try this if you are OK creating a new commit (copy the repo first).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get rid of the changes currently present in your `git status` output, and you want to switch to your branch.

Git will complain about switching branches when you have unstaged changes of tracked files present in your working directory. Git will *not* complain about switching branches when untracked files are present in your working directory.

So let's break it down.

To get rid of the (un)staged changes run `git reset --hard`. This discards changes to the tracked files.

Now, we will still see untracked files present when we run `git status`. But at this point, we should be able to switch branches. When you switch to your branch, and run `git status` there should be nothing there, *except* for those untracked files.

Finally, if you want to get rid of them, you can either delete them manually, or use a command designed for that: run `git clean -nd` - this will do a "dry run", listing all the files what would be deleted (I always prefer doing a dry run so that I don't do anything regrettable, `-d` will remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files). If you're happy with the output, run it for real: `git clean -df` (`-f` is for force, it is required in most cases by default).

Answer (score 0):

Unexpectedly, the culprit is Dropbox. 
After moving my project from Dropbox, `git reset --hard` worked as expected.

Comment: This should have been expected. Dropbox attempts to *control* the files (because they are shared across multiple machines). Git attempts to *control* the files (because it is a *version control system*, after all). Who do you expect to win this fight for control, and why? Is it wise to have your files conduct MMA cage battles like this? :-)